# Definition by Recursion - Need for Rigour

Tags: induction, definition, recursion

Suppose you define the factorial $n!$ by
\begin{align}
\tag{1}0!&:=1,\\
\tag{2}(n+1)!&:=(n+1)n!.
\end{align}
Consider the following argument showing that $n!$ is a uniquely defined function.

Let
$$
P(n):="n!\text{ is uniquely defined }".
$$
Then $(1)$ gives $P(0)$ and $(2)$ gives $P(n)\implies P(n+1)$. So, by induction, $P(n)$ is true for every natural number $n$, that is, the factorial $n!$ has been uniquely defined.

> **Question:** Why is this argument erroneous?

There might be some ambiguity talking about $n!$ in advance of knowing that it exists, but what if we write
$$
P'(n):="\text{The symbol }n!\text{ is uniquely defined }".
$$

In the end, is it the impossibility of translating $P'(n)$ in, say, the formal language of ZF that is problematic?

Comment: Looks very strange what you are asking...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have to distinguish between *first-order* arithmetic and *second-order* one.

The original (1889) Peano version is second-order; see [Arithmetices Principia](https://archive.org/stream/arithmeticespri00peangoog#page/n22/mode/2up), page 1 has :

> *Axiomata*
>
> > 1) $1 ∈ N$ [...]
> >
> > 9) $(k∈Class \land 1∈k∧x∈N∧∀x(x∈k→(x+1)∈k)→N⊆k)$.

Also Landau express his **Axiom 5** (Induction) as :

> Let there be given a set $\mathfrak M$ of natural numbers, with the following properties:
>
> > I) $1$ belongs to $\mathfrak M$. [...]

In a modern treatment of second-order arithmetic (see e.g.Dirk van Dalen, [Logic and Structure](https://books.google.it/books?id=u0wlXPHATDcC&pg=PA152) (5th ed - 2013), page 152), we need the following axioms :

> > 1) $∀x¬(0=S(y))$
> >
> > 2) $∀xy(S(x) ∧ S(y) → x = y)$
> >
> > 3) $∀P(P(0)∧∀x(P(x) → P(S(x))) → ∀xP(x))$.

We can for simplicity extend the language with $+$ and $\times$, but we can define them, according to [Church](https://books.google.it/books?id=JDLQOMKbdScC&pg=PA322), as follows :

> $x+y=z \leftrightarrow \forall F(F(0,x) \land \forall x \forall y (F(x,y) \to F(S(x),S(y)) \to F(y,z))$.

With this definition, and the corresponding one for $\times$, we can prove existence and uniqueness of the corresponding operations.

---

In f-o arithmetic, we cannot prove the existence of a function, because we cannot quantify neither predicate nor function letters, i.e. we cannot express in it $\exists F (F(\ldots))$.

Thus, we need the so-called rucursive axioms for sum and product :

> > $x+0=x$
> >
> > $x+S(y)=S(x+y)$

and similar for $\times$.

The $+$ symbol is a function symbol, interpreted - according to the "standard" semantical specifications - as an operation :

> $+ : N × N → N$, where $N$ is the domain of the interpretation.

With the equality axiom for *function* symbols :

> $∀x_1 \ldots x_n y_1 \ldots y_n \ (x_1=y_1 \land \ldots x_n=y_n → f(x_1,\ldots, x_n) = f(y_1,\ldots, y_n))$,

"applied" to $+$ we get :

> > $\forall x_1 x_2 y_1 y_2 \ (x_1=y_1 \land x_2=y_2 \to x_1+x_2=y_1+y_2)$.

We can say that the "existence" and "uniqueness" of the $+$ and $\times$ operations are built-in into the syntax and semantics of the language.

---

---

If we are working in *set theory*, the arithmetical "notions" are nor more primitive : we define suitable "substitute" for $0$ and the *successor* operation as well as for $+$ and $\times$.

In this case, we can *prove* Peano axioms (*Induction* included) and the uniqueness of the sum and product function, via *recursion*; see :

- George Tourlakis, [Lectures in Logic and Set Theory : Volume 2, Set Theory](https://books.google.it/books?id=nparMXao59QC&pg=PA246) (2003), page 246;
- Kenneth Kunen, [The Foundations of Mathematics](https://books.google.it/books?id=_B_oQQAACAAJ) (2009), page 43 :

> On $\omega$ we already have the Principle of Ordinary Induction (**Theorem 1.8.14** : For any set $X$ : if $0 \in X$ and $\forall y \in X(S(y) \in X)$, then $X$ contains all natural numbers.), whereas *recursion* would be used to justify the definition of the factorial ($!$) function by:
>
> > $0! = 1$
> >
> > $(n + 1)! = n!(n + 1)$.